# Yeoman grunt fails on mocha test

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs

I'm taking my first spin with Yeoman, but running into problems when I get to the "grunt test" and "grunt" calls in terminal.

It seems to fail on mocha in both cases.

```
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
4 files lint free.

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning ".tmp"...OK

Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task
File .tmp/scripts/hello.js created.

Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/
   create .tmp/styles/main.css

Running "compass:server" (compass) task
unchanged app/styles/main.scss

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Starting connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing index.htmlFatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

I cant seem to find any references to this error in Grunt or Mocha.

Where should I be checking to resolve this?

Comment: What version of node and yeoman are you using? Which generator did you use to create this setup? Did you modify the Gruntfile or any other part of the app after it has been generated?

Comment: I blew everything away and started over and it seems to be working now.  Thanks!

Comment: This can happen if the ELF loader in the phantomjs binary is set to the wrong path.